# Video ad JS Vast Tag example

Tags: ads, vast, video-ads

can you please suggest me some documentation from where i can see some example for video ad Java script Tag. I already implemented VAST/VPAID with vast XML. Now i need Java Script Vast Tag. I read a documentation here
[enter link description here](https://inneractive.jira.com/wiki/display/DevWiki/JavaScript+Ad+Tag)

```
Inneractive JS Ad Tag Start

 * -=====================================================================-
 *   Inneractive JS Ad Tag
 * -=====================================================================-
 *   Update Date: February, 10th, 2014
 *   Further documentation found here: 
 *   https://inneractive.jira.com/wiki/display/DevWiki/JavaScript+Ad+Tag
 * -=====================================================================-


<!-- Final Ad is attached to this DIV. Can be placed anywhere on the page. -->
<div id='iaAdPlaceholder'></div>
<script>
    try {
        (function() {   
            if (typeof ia === 'undefined') {
                ia = {};
            }

            // CHANGE AD SETTINGS BELOW.
            // More details about the different parameters can be found here:
            // https://inneractive.jira.com/wiki/display/DevWiki/JavaScript+Ad+Tag#JavaScriptAdTag-RequestParameters
            ia.adSettings = {
                APP_ID:'MyCompany_MyApp',
                IS_MOBILE_WEB: false,
                IS_ORMMA_SUPPORT: false,
                IS_MRAID_SUPPORT: false,
                IS_VIDEO_SUPPORT : false,
                IS_INTERSTITIAL_AD: false,
                IS_FLOATING_BANNER: false, // Glues banner ad position to bottom of the page, even when the page is scrolled. Supported only for banner ads, on iOS (>= 5.0) and Android (>= 2.2). Does not apply when IS_INTERSTITIAL_AD: true.
                IMEI_MD5: '',
                IMEI_SHA1: '',
                IMSI_MD5: '',
                IMSI_SHA1: '',
                ANDROID_ID_MD5: '',
                ANDROID_ID_SHA1: '',
                IDFA:'',
                IDFV:'',
                PACKAGE_NAME:'', // In Android - The application name as a reverse domain notation string (e.g., 'com.inneractive.adTag'). In iOS - the App Store Id from the iTunes URL (e.g., "123456789" for the following iTunes link: 'https://itunes.apple.com/iw/app/myApp/id123456789?mt=8').
                CATEGORY:'', // e.g., Music
                AGE:'',
                GENDER:'',
                KEYWORDS: '', // e.g., Rock,Pop,Jazz,Blues
                LOCATION:'',
                GPS_COORDINATES:'',
                DEVICE_WIDTH:'', // resolution width of the device
                DEVICE_HEIGHT:'', // resolution height of the device
                MOBILE_NETWORK_CODE:'',
                MOBILE_COUNTRY_CODE:'',
                NETWORK:'', // values are 3G or WIFI
                REQUIRED_WIDTH:'',
                REQUIRED_HEIGHT:'',
                FAILOVER: ''
            };
            // CHANGE AD SETTINGS  ABOVE.
        })();
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
</script>
<script src='http://cdn2.inner-active.mobi/wv-js/iaAdTagInternal.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<!-- Inneractive JS Ad Tag End -->
```

Is it? How and where will i add all event tracking links?
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take a look at JW Player's Ad Tester here:

http://demo.jwplayer.com/ad-tester/

Here you can see everything in action.

If you just want to see a typical vast response, simply go to the URL in the 'Ad Tag to Load' input field.

Comment: I don't want to test my ad. I just want to create a JavaScript response from my server. For that i need a model JS video ad tag in which we will have creative URL and all tracking URLs for each events. Now i am creating VAST/VPAID response. My client needs JavaScript response also.

Comment: Yes- as I said; "If you just want to see a typical vast response, simply go to the URL in the 'Ad Tag to Load' input field"

Comment: Infact, let me just give you the link in case you still don't understand ;)
GO TO:
http://www.adotube.com/php/services/player/OMLService.php?avpid=oRYYzvQ&platform_version=vast20&ad_type=linear&groupbypass=1&HTTP_REFERER=http://www.longtailvideo.com&video_identifier=longtailvideo.com,test

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand. From the above link , i get a VAST response(that is xml), and my system is currently handling this part very well. But my problem is, instead of creating a VAST xml response, my client asked me for a JS response (that will be same as this VAST xml with creative  and all event's links). Is it possible? Still i don't have any idea

Comment: Sorry Manu, I don't really understand what you want? You can't replace an XML response with a javascript response - do you mean a VPAID response as opposed to VAST?

Comment: VAST and VPAID both are XML. I Just want to create a JS response that an ad player able to handle(means that ad player can able to capture creative url, and all tracking urls).

Comment: Aha! You want a VPAID response, with a javascript creative- try this:
http://ryanthompson591.github.io/vpaidExamples/

Answer (score 0):

Google ad tags
https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/client-side/tags

IMA providers
https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/VAST_Samples